# How to set the maxLength property of an EditText programmatically in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I would like to programmatically set the `maxLength` property of `EditText` as I don't want to set it in the layout file. I can't see any set method related to `maxLength`.

Answer (score 1):

You must set it as an input filter, and can set an array of input filter in same time.

You can set the maxLenght like this code:

```
field.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilter.LengthFilter(data.maximum ?: 0))
```